# How to write more than 1 line of text delimited by \n using show_alert()?

Tags: r, shiny, alert, sweetalert, shinywidgets

I have recently found that there is a possibility to display sweet alerts in shiny using the package `shinyWidgets`.

I am trying to put more than 1 line of text delimited by `\n` in the function `show_alert()` but I cannot find any way to get this.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want (ignore the different format of the letters or the indentation, I am not interested in having two lines with different format).

[image]

Attempts:

1. `text = paste("This data is....", "Please, be careful with...", sep="\n")`
2. `text = paste("This data is....", "\n", "Please, be careful with...")`
3. `text = paste0("This data is....", "\n", "Please, be careful with...")`
4. `text = "This data is....\nPlease, be careful with..."`

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Sweet Alert examples"),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "success",
    label = "Submit type of data",
    icon = icon("check")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$success, {
    show_alert(
      title = "Are you sure?",
      text = "This data is....\nPlease, be careful with...",
      type = "warning"
    )
  })

}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does anybody know how to help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `show_alert`'s `html` parameter:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Sweet Alert examples"),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "success",
    label = "Submit type of data",
    icon = icon("check")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$success, {
    show_alert(
      title = "Are you sure?",
      text = HTML("This data is....<br>Please, be careful with..."),
      type = "warning",
      html = TRUE
    )
  })
  
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: I didn't think about using `html`, thank you so much for your quick response!

Comment: Done! (I was waiting until I was allowed to accept it, for that reason I didn't accept the answer when I answered you)